# why expect shell script for 'obexctl' not working as Expected

Tags: shell, bluetooth, expect, obex, obexftp

I want to send a file using bluetooth from one device to another device. For that i am using obex which has a command called 'obexctl'. It works as 
described in this ... [Please Take a look into this Doc](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/bluetooth/bluez/docs/reference/sending-files)

[image]

[image]

This is how sending file works. For automating this process i have written one shell script using expect. which is as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
   set address [lindex $argv 0]
   set prompt "#"
   spawn obexctl
   sleep 2
   expect -re $prompt
   send "connect $address\r"
   sleep 5
   send "quit\r"
```

but it didnt work.  It doesnt fully execute that connect command.and exit the code. Please let me know if any of you know the solution.

Comment: Single quotes have no meaning in Tcl/expect. Your `$prompt` variable holds a 3-character string. Use double quotes, or `{braces}` (which are Tcl's non-interpolating quotes)

Comment: Also, your `send`  commands do not "hit Enter" -- use a carriage return like `send "quit\r"`

Comment: And your shebang line is missing the leading slash before "usr"

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman for your reply and yes i have updated my script. now let me update you whether it worked or not. Thanks

Comment: #!/usr/bin/expect -f
   set address [lindex $argv 0]
   set prompt "#"
   spawn obexctl
   sleep 2
   expect -re $prompt
   send "connect $address\r"
   sleep 5
   send "quit\r"
I have updated my code like this

Comment: Send command is not working. actually. it is not sending connect command.

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script to see why not.

Comment: Thanks, Its working now.